# Will the custom battery settings set in Windows Power Manager hold when I dual boot with Ubuntu and use Ubuntu instead of Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, power-management, windows-10, battery

So, I used Windows Power Manager to limit my batter threshold to 60%. Will that hold when I am using Ubuntu in a dual boot system or will the battery charge to 100%. Currently my battery percentage is showing 100%. What does it mean? Does it mean my battery is charged to 60% or 100% ? Also if the settings in Windows doesn't hold in Ubuntu,is there a way I can limit my battery percentage in Ubuntu?

Comment: One question at a time, that's how the site works. In answer to your first question, "No. No, it will not retain settings from Windows in Ubuntu."

Answer (score 0):

While this was already answered in a comment, I thought I'd me more specific. When using a dual boot, Ubuntu and Windows are *entirely separate*. Changing settings on one of them will not effect the other unless you modify the firmware of your computer in some way. This means that A. your computer will not stop charging at 60% and B. when Ubuntu says 100%, it means 100%. It is important to note, however, that as Ubuntu runs with *many* different combinations of hardware its never been tested on and tries to work with all of them, this cannot be guaranteed, and battery readings are sometimes inaccurate. Chances are, though, as long as Ubuntu gives a percentage at all and that percentage is not apparently broken (e.g. stuck at 100%) it is accurate.